# Change the path where Apache WAMP access to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

We work with a **WordPress** in **Apache** but we need to work with the same **DataBase** and **files** in differents PCs.

To do this, I know how change the path where apache search the files (`Wordpress` in that case) where we put in a Dropbox but I don't know how I can change the path to PHPMyAdmin to add it in Dropbox.

Comment: Sharing phpMyAdmin files will not help you. What you need is a centrally located mysql server which is shared and accessed by different PCs (on which code is developed). If you just want to share the database file (which out collaborating) then you can just export the database in `.sql` format and upload it to dropbox for others collaborators to download and use.

Comment: The problem is that if we are working at the same time and modifying the database, uploading the '.sql' will overwrite the changes of the others.

Comment: Correct. That's why you need a centrally located mysql server which has a shared access.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zipkundan. I will do this.

Comment: @zipkundan, perhaps you could make your comment into an answer so that I can up vote it and Brecht can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing phpMyAdmin files will not help you. What you need is a centrally located mysql server which is shared and accessed by different PCs (on which code is developed). If you just want to share the database file (with out collaborating) then you can just export the database in .sql format and upload it to dropbox for others collaborators to download and use.